# Swift 2.0 two table views in one view controller cellForRowIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Ive  seen a few questions here about this but no defitnive answer Im using an up to date version of Xcode and swift...

Im trying to work with two table views in one view controller here is my cellForRowIndexPath function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: UITableViewCell!

    if(tableView == self.allTableView){

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BMRadioAllTableViewCell

            cell.mixImage.image = mixPhotoArray[indexPath.item]

            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            cell.mixDateLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(mixDateArray[indexPath.item])


    }

    if(tableView == self.featuredTableView){
    // SET UP THE NEXT TABLE VIEW

    }


    return cell
    }
```

Im getting the error "Value of type UITableViewCell has no member "xxxx" so its obviously not registering the change to cell I'm making in the if statement.

I have tried various other ways, like declaring the variable within the if statement and returning it there. But you get the error "Missing return in a function expected to return UITableViewCell" since you need to get it outside the if statement.

Comment: You may want to consider separating your tableview's data source into their own classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two different cell types for two different tables, you should make your code look something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(tableView == self.allTableView){
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BMRadioAllTableViewCell

        cell.mixImage.image = mixPhotoArray[indexPath.item]

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        cell.mixDateLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(mixDateArray[indexPath.item])

        return cell;
    } else {
        var cell = ...
        // SET UP THE NEXT TABLE VIEW
        return cell
    }
}
```

There's no need to have a single generic `cell` variable that handles both tables.

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn't really have to do with you trying to configure two table views.

Even though you're casting the result of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` to `BMRadioAllTableViewCell`, you are then assigning it to a variable of type `UITableViewCell!`.  As such, it will be a compiler error for you to access fields of `BMRadioAllTableViewCell`.

You would either need to change the `cell` type to `BMRadioAllTableViewCell`, or have a locally scoped variable of the correct type that you configure and then assign to `cell`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell!

    if(tableView == self.allTableView){

        let bmRadioAllCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BMRadioAllTableViewCell

        bmRadioAllCell.mixImage.image = mixPhotoArray[indexPath.item]

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        bmRadioAllCell.mixDateLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(mixDateArray[indexPath.item])

        cell = bmRadioAllCell
    }

    if(tableView == self.featuredTableView){
    // SET UP THE NEXT TABLE VIEW

    }


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot, that works! Only issue Im having now is that after completing the first if statement for allTableView everything ok. But it won't seem to run the other if statement, Ive changed it to an else added a println to check  in the second tableView set up but it won't execute it. Any Ideas?

Comment: If you never seem to get the `tableView == self.featuredTableView` part of the code to execute, you may have forgotten to connect the `featuredTableView` `IBOutlet` in your storyboard.